# swiftのニュースリーダーアプリでサムネイル画像を表示する方法について

Tags: swift, ios, uitableview, swift4

テーブルビューを使ってニュースリーダーアプリを作っています。

RSSからタイトルやリンクを取得して、テーブルビューに表示するところまでは出来たのですが
RSSからサムネイルを取得する方法が分かりません。

RSSからどのようにすればサムネイル画像を取得し、それをテーブルビューのセルに表示できるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RSSにサムネイル画像の情報が含まれていないのであれば、指定したURL(webページ)のキャプチャ画像を生成してくれるサービスがいくつかあるのでこれらを利用する方法が考えられます。

[Page2Images](http://www.page2images.com/)
[指定URLのPC・タブレット・スマホの「キャプチャ画像」を自動表示するデモアプリを作ってみた！ - paiza開発日誌](https://paiza.hatenablog.com/entry/2016/03/01/%E6%8C%87%E5%AE%9AURL%E3%81%AEPC%E3%83%BB%E3%82%BF%E3%83%96%E3%83%AC%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%83%BB%E3%82%B9%E3%83%9E%E3%83%9B%E3%81%AE%E3%80%8C%E3%82%AD%E3%83%A3%E3%83%97%E3%83%81%E3%83%A3%E7%94%BB%E5%83%8F)